# Dojo Radiobutton - check one of them programatically

Tags: javascript, json, dojo, dijit.form

I have a group of RadioButton dojo dijits and my task is to check one of them based on a request response json. Json will have a value that corresponds to one the RadioButtons value within group1
for example:
   {
    "group1":"1"
   }

```
<input type="radio" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/RadioButton" name="group1" value="1"/> <label>1</label>
<input type="radio" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/RadioButton" name="group1" value="2"/> <label>2</label>
<input type="radio" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/RadioButton" name="group1" value="3"/> <label>3</label>
```

How do I do this in a good way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your RadioButton widgets happen to be within a `dijit/form/Form`, the most convenient way by far to do this would be by setting the form's `value`, since `dijit/form/_FormMixin`'s value setter will automatically map the value to the appropriate RadioButton widget.

```
form.set('value', { group1: '1' });
```

(Even if the form has other fields, calling `set('value')` with an object with only one property will only update that one field in the form.)

Barring this option (if you're not in a `dijit/form/Form` and aren't able to use one for some reason), you can do something like what trincot suggested, but since you're using widgets, you need to set the appropriate widget's `checked` property, not just the input node's directly:

```
registry.getEnclosingWidget(query('[name=group1][value=1]')[0]).set('checked', true);
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0kee7dL7/) demonstrating both approaches.

Comment: Thank you Ken and Trincot. 

Ken's suggestion worked like a charm. I used the approach of setting form's value property. 

I tried the latter approach as well and it did not work for my specific situation. The reason is that I have a collection of these widgets so there are several groups of radiobuttons with name=group1. So the dojo query returns a bunch of these widgets back for the name/value combination.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to do that with `dojo`

```
function test(json) {
    var obj = dojo.fromJson(json);
    for (prop in obj) {
        dojo.query('input[name="' + prop + '"][value="' + obj[prop] + '"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
}
```

Where `json` is the string you receive, and `obj` is the corresponding object, after decoding from `JSON`. This code goes through the properties of that object (such as "group1"), and then finds the element with a `css` selector by `name` and `value`, and then sets the `checked` attribute of the found element, if any.

I have put this in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/za0Ldm70/), where the `test` function is called after pressing a button.